# Check if a string contains any of the strings from an List

Tags: java, java-stream

I am quite new to java and currently stuck and do not know how to proceed.

What I want to do is to check if a string contains any words from a list of words and if yes output them.

In my case all strings will have a similar text like this one (example with 5 mins):

```
Set timer to five minutes
```

or this one:

```
Timer five minutes
```

This is my current code with some comments what I am trying to do:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream; 

class GFG { 

// Driver code 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 

String example = Set timer to five minutes

    Stream<String> stream = Stream.of(("Timer", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten") //The stream/array would be much bigger since I want to cover every number till 200 

//Now I thought I can use stream filter to check if example contains the word Timer and any of the words of the Stream and if it does I want to use the output to trigger something else

    if(stream.filter(example -> example .contains(NOTSUREWHATTOPUTHERE))) {
       //If detected that String contains Timer and Number, then create timer 
    } 
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice/help?

regards

Comment: What if the input string is "Sing for two minutes"?

Comment: @naman Good question, so best would be to also make sure that the word Timer is definitely in there. I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Another approach could be creating `@Builder class Action { String type; String value; }` used further in `String example = "Set timer to five minutes"; Set<String> words = Arrays.stream(example.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toSet()); Set<String> actions = Set.of("Timer", "Music"); Set<String> values = Set.of("One", "Two", "Three",...); Action.ActionBuilder actionBuilder = Action.builder(); actions.stream().filter(words::contains).findFirst().ifPresent(s -> { actionBuilder.type(s); values.stream().filter(words::contains).findFirst().ifPresent(actionBuilder::value); });//Use action further }`.

Comment: could you post that maybe as an answer, it seems that the comment section makes it quite hard to read the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
String[] words = { "Timer", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

String example = "Set timer to five minutes";

String exLower = example.toLowerCase();
if (Stream.of(words).anyMatch(word -> exLower.contains(word.toLowerCase()))) {
    //
}
```

That code will at least check correctly, even when words have different upper-/lower-case, but it fails if the text has a word embedded in another word, e.g. text `"stone"` will match because `"one"` is found.

To fix that, the "easiest" would be to convert the word list to a regex.

```
String[] words = { "Timer", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

String example = "Set timer to five minutes";

String regex = Stream.of(words).map(Pattern::quote)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|", "(?i)\\b(?:", ")\\b"));
if (Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(example).find()) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Without getting into string parsing and pattern detection which themselves are quite broad. But why not use `split` and collect the words `toSet` and then perform contains for any of them under the `list` provided?

Comment: Thank you for this. I have one more question. The word Timer needs to be in the string and one of the numbers as a word. How can I make sure the if case is only triggered if it contains the word timer and a number ?

Comment: @Salexes I could sense that coming hence was asking in a comment to the question. What if input is "Sing for two minutes"? How does the application behave?

Comment: @Salexes Do the test twice, once with `Timer` as the only word in the list, and once with all the numbers in the word list.

Comment: @Naman It needs to contain the word Timer aswell. Should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: @Salexes Yes you should, and it's not too late. Edit the question and clarify it.